# Select many to many entity collection using DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to entities that have ManyToMany relation with linking table. Like this:

```
class User
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="favorite_posts",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $favoritePosts;
}

class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="favoritePosts")
     */
    private $usersInFavorite;
}
```

And I can get all user's favorite posts using a User entity object:

```
$favorites = $user->getFavoritesPosts();
```

But I have no idea how to get **EXACTLY THE SAME** result using DQL or Doctrine Query Builder. Under result i mean an array of POST entity objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [exemple](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#queries-for-application-use-cases)

If you want to fetch it by dql,

```
$dql = "SELECT p FROM Posts p INNER JOIN p.$usersInFavorite u WHERE u= ?1";

$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                       ->setParameter(1, $user);
$favoritePosts = $query->getResult();
```

I tested it this time and i found the results as requested.

if you have the id of the user entity instead of the entity the same code will work with $user being the id of the user.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work: `Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.` I believe it is not so easy.

Comment: replace the id WHERE u.id by u.user_id

Comment: i edited the answer, assuming that your methode to get the id of the user is getuser_id() and that $user is the User entity that you already fetch.

Comment: I actually did the same, it throws a error `Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.` And it is not strange: I can't see any logic in your way, sorry.

Comment: i recreated the entire scenario and you are totally right :). Let me get you the correct DQL. i remember this issue now.

Comment: This time i fully tested the solution.

Comment: Oh my god it works! I didn't get how it works yet, but I will. Thank you!